# ​How can I reference a classpath file in the java command​?

Tags: java, maven-dependency-plugin

It is possible to generate a classpath file during a build, for instance using the [maven-dependency-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) to create a file named *classpath*:

`mvn dependency:build-classpath -Dmdep.outputFile=classpath`

How can I then use the file when invoking java from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

Since [JDK9](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/9-all-relnotes.html#JDK-8027634) the java command supports @-file arguments where the file contents are used in place of the [@-file](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/java.htm#JSWOR-GUID-4856361B-8BFD-4964-AE84-121F5F6CF111) placeholder.

Example:

```bash
$ cat classpath
./clojure-1.11.1.jar:./spec.alpha-0.3.218.jar

$ java -cp @classpath clojure.main
Clojure 1.11.1
user=>
```